# Does each Browser have their own default CSS for each HTML element?

Tags: css

Does each browser have their own CSS for each HTML element and sometimes browsers can have the same CSS for the same HTML elements? Does each browser have the freedom to pick what type of CSS to do for default rendering for HTML elements?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54749741/8620333

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Every browser has their own default styling.
you can check chrome's default styling here:
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css

Comment: what could be a reason for them to have their own styling?